# How do I allow a specific program Send as access in Outlook?

Tags: email, exchange

I have been searching around on the web and the closest thing I found was [This Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/I-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-email-address-information-or-sending-email-on-my-behalf-86cc5ece-379e-45e3-b8eb-3fefba09946b?CorrelationId=828e275c-b89a-476d-a66a-b605a3c0cf4e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc301271775). It states that I need to click allow when the security warning pops up. however using Sage software means my colleague would need to press this 20 - 30 times per session... This is obviously too time consuming...

It also mentions the trust centre within Outlook under Programmatic access... However we are running an exchange environment and its locked down. We couldn't change it as it would allow all programs to access Outlook. This a security hazard. So how can I allow ONLY Sage to send emails on a users behalf?

Is there a way to add exceptions in the trust centre of Outlook? or would it be via Exchange that this would be done?

**Edit**

I also forgot to add that Trusted Publishers are also disabled within Outlook... I am wondering if there is any specific Registry keys to edit to allow this?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am IT I am diagnosing it and trying to find a fix... its not solely related to a network issue... it could be an issue with Outlook itself and its permissions there are registry keys that mention it they could be edited someway I just don't know the correct method

Comment: @DavidPostill if corporate IT support questions were off topic that means most Outlook questions would be off topic, and there would not be an "exchange" tag as that is purely corporate... and Sage for that matter

Comment: NathanTaylor, no, not at all. Many people want Exchange non corporate reasons. And as for Outlook - that's just ignorable. And @DavidPostill was right, hence why it's moved!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32-bit version of Outlook then free [Advanced Security for Outlook](http://download.cnet.com/Advanced-Security-for-Outlook/3000-2369_4-10431585.html) add-in will help. It allows access for specific programs.